# How to specify a default and global value for Laravel max job attempts

Tags: laravel, queue, jobs

I'm using Laravel and I'm working with jobs and queues.

As I know, Laravel jobs will attempt unlimited number of times when we do not specify number of tries in our job classes.

`public $tries = 5;`

How can I set a default value for Laravel max attempts (public $tries) so that we don't need to add this variable on every job class?
Is there any key that I can use on config files?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create a BaseJob class with that property and the make all your Job extend from that BaseJob class?

Comment: You could define this when starting the worker as well: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#max-job-attempts-and-timeout

Comment: @AmirRezaAzizi You are welcome! Please mark the question as resolved and select the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Or create a queues default configs Trait and then call it in your jobs.